# What is making this du command error with invalid options?

Tags: linux, unix, diskspace

To get a breakdown of disk usage, always use

```
du -m -h -s * -c | sort -h
```

It returns a list like this:

```
4.0K    merge.sh
8.0K    mergeforums_01.sh
5.2M    _vt
82M     sbc
166M    ip2location.sql
184M    IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB5.CSV
1.6G    _yo.zip
20G     sle
22G     total
```

But in this one branch of directories, I get this:

```
du: invalid option -- 'e'
du: invalid option -- 'd'
du: invalid option -- 'i'
du: invalid option -- 't'
du: invalid option -- '4'
du: invalid option -- '.'
du: invalid option -- 'p'
du: invalid option -- 'p'
```

It looks like it is telling me to edit 4.pp

What is going on?

Comment: Is the file called `-edit44.pp`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems like there's a file whose name starts with a dash `-`.

Use `--` so that filenames expanded are not interpreted as options:

```
du -m -h -s -c -- * | sort -h
```

Comment: @DanAllen: Underscores shouldn't cause any issue.

Comment: Thank you for the correction.  I did find files with dashes in the names.  Good correction, thank you.